# Not able to use binding with navcontroller

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-viewbinding

Here is the code :

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentFirstBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.btnOpen.setOnClickListener {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.secondFragment)
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

At line: `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.secondFragment)` I'm getting error as Type mismatch required view found view?

My question is why we can't combine navcontroller with view binding?

And is there any resources to learn restrictions of using view binding

Comment: You can replace `Navigation.findNavController(view)` with `findNavController()` and the should go away.

Comment: I tried it. It's not working

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No not getting any error but the app crashes after clicking on button

Comment: What exception is thrown on crash , check the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `view` use `binding.root`
Like this:

```
Navigation.findNavController(binding.root).navigate(R.id.secondFragment)
```

binding.root is reference to root view.

Comment: Thanks... This is working... I found the same solution later on but forgot to post it...